# How to disable the default set layout?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to set a connection page using the Zend framework 2. To achieve this, I need to set a connection page without the use of the set Layout. I've tried to add this line to IndexController

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```

Doing that I get this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_helper' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in IndexController.php on line 10

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

can you try it ?

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTerminal(true);

return $viewModel;
```

Comment: You don't need to set any variables. Just use `$viewModel->setTerminal(true)`

Comment: i know, but it can avoid a second question, on how to use viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 simple ways. Check this out: http://ikorolchuk.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/zend-framework-2-disable-layout.html

The simpliest:

```
$this->layout('layout/empty');
```